# Detect specific multiple key strokes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have found other threads with this question, and with great answers. However, reading all of them, I simply do not know what to do. People say how to use `keyCode` to detect keystrokes, but everywhere I look, people say `keyCode` is deprecated, and should not be used. Another option I saw was to use `e.key` or `e.code`. However, `e.code` came up undefined when I tried in **chrome, Windows**. `e.key` worked...partially. It did not give a value for keys such as the control key.

Is there a non-deprecated way I could use to detect multiple keystrokes, where extra keystrokes also count. For example, I want something to happen when I press `CTRL + ENTER`, but not when I press `CTRL + ALT + ENTER`. I am open to using jQuery.

Thanks!

Mike

---

Note: Before closing this question due to finding another thread that supposedly has the answer, would you mind commenting below. I have seen several threads with very similar questions to mine, but without the answer, I am looking for.

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: `e.key` works when pressing `CTRL`. Are you using `keyup` or `keydown` instead of `keypress`? `keypress` doesn't capture all keys. Would help if you could add some code.

Comment: @kmoser: I don't have code, this is a general question asking about detecting keystrokes. @Daniel_Knights: I did `console.log(e.key)`, but when I pressed `ctrl` it did not log anything, not even a newline.

Comment: @MikeSmith Without seeing your code, the best we can do is point you to existing answers.

Comment: I don't have any code. All I want is a way to detect multiple keystrokes from scratch. The reason I made a new question is because all the working answers seem to be using keyCodes, which I've been told is now deprecated.